# Узнать значение поля другого класса

Tags: python, ооп

Подскажите, как в классе `A` получить доступ к поля `self.d` в классе `B`?
Как полю `self.f` класса `A` присвоить значение поля `self.d` класса `B`?

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = 'a'

    def __str__(self):
        self.f = B.d # Ошибка
        return self.f

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = 'b'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.d

a = A()
print(a)
```

Comment: место `B.d` напишите `B().d`

Comment: Никак. У **класса** `B` нет переменной `d`.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы класс `A` получил доступ к полю `self.d` класса `B` и присвоил значение полю `self.f`, можно изменить ваш код, сделав экземпляр класса `B` членом класса `A`.

Вот исправленный пример:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = 'a'
        self.b_instance = B() # Создаем экземпляр класса B внутри класса A

    def __str__(self):
        self.f = self.b_instance.d # Получаем доступ к переменной self.d из экземпляра класса B
        return self.f

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = 'b'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.d

a = A()
print(a)
```

Также можно прибегнуть к другому решению: сделать поле `self.d` класса `B` статическим:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = 'a'

    def __str__(self):
        self.f = B.d # Обращаемся к статической переменной d класса B напрямую
        return self.f

class B:
    d = 'b' # Сделаем переменную d статической

    def __str__(self):
        return self.d

a = A()
print(a)
```